# How to send path in php include statement

Tags: php

I want to keep my paypal script in a different directory than my application directory.  With that said here is my problem. When I use a path with the include statement, it doesnt find the page.  I am calling the include file from "mysite.com/cart/pp_express/processed.php"

This doesnt work

```
include (__DIR__ . "/mywebite.com/cart/cart.php");
```

This does not work

```
$file = "mysite.com/cart/cart.php";
include($file);
```

This workes

```
$file = "cart.php";
include($file);
```

So then I created a function with the include statement to send only the file name in a variable.  This works.

```
$deleted_flag = "no";
$file = "cart.php";
    function includeFile($file, $deleted_flag) {
        include($file);
    }
        includeFile($file, $deleted_flag);
```

Then I created a function with the include statement to send the entire path in a variable.  It doesnt work.  The following is the one I need to have working

```
$deleted_flag = "no";
$file = "mysite.com/cart/cart.php";
    function includeFile1($file, $deleted_flag) {
        include($file);  
    }   
        includeFile1($file, $deleted_flag);
```

Comment: so, you knew that inclusion of wrong path (probably you meant URL, but then you have to add protocol) does not work, but you still created wrapper around it and now want to fix wrapper, not the original problem, is it right?

Comment: you need to use either absolute path (it starts with /) or use proper relative part (starts with ..)

Comment: These were just examples of what I have tried, before I asked for help.  been working on this all day

Answer (score 0):

`__DIR__` points to the folder in which **the file calling `__DIR__`** is located.

Let's say you have the following structure:

```
/var/www/html/index.php
             /classes/class.php
             /cart/cart.php
```

In index.php, `__DIR__` will be `/var/www/html`. In class.php, `__DIR__` will be `/var/www/html/classes`.

So, to include `cart.php` from index.php, you'd need to write:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/cart/cart.php');
```

To include `cart.php` from class.php, you'd need to write:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/../cart/cart.php');
```